# nodehandle parameter

Tags: ros, rosparam, nodehandle, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am reading the tutorial on the website http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server
But I am not sure understand the following the *Default value version*.

```
ros::NodeHandle nh;
std::string global_name, relative_name, default_param;
if (nh.getParam("/global_name", global_name))
{
 ...
}

if (nh.getParam("relative_name", relative_name))
{
...
}

// Default value version  
nh.param<std::string>("default_param", default_param, "default_value");
```

So in the *defalut value version*, **nh.param** does the same function as get parameter? What is the "default_param", default_param, "default_value"?  The first **"default_param"** with double quotation means the name of parameter right? And the **default_param** without double quotation means: if the nodehandle **"default_param"** has a value ,then we pass the value to **default_param**? Otherwise we set the value of  **default_param** to be **"default_value"** ?

#### Am I understand this correctly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310051/nodehandle-parameter/) by [zhonghao](https://answers.ros.org/users/38441/zhonghao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2018-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yes simply this command

```
nh.param<std::string>("param_name", variable, "value");
```

checks if param_name is exist the the command pass the value of param in variable but if the param doesn't exist
then the command pass "value" to variable

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2018-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2